# Perl Reading Text File

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures

I am trying to read in a text file and do some splitting up of the file with the intention of adding the data into a database.
The text file looks something like.

```
object-group network og-net-network-hostname-blah 
 description blah
 network-object host 192.168.0.1
 network-object host 192.168.0.2
 network-object host 192.168.0.3
 network-object host 192.168.0.4
 network-object host 192.168.0.5
 network-object host 192.168.0.6
object-group network og-net-network-hostname-anotherblah 
 description blah2
 network-object host 192.168.1.1
 network-object host 192.168.1.2
 network-object host 192.168.1.3
 network-object host 192.168.1.4
 network-object host 192.168.1.5
 network-object host 192.168.1.6
```

What I am wanting to add to the database is as follows.

```
Column Name => og-net-network-hostname-blah,og-net-network-hostname-anotherblah
Column Description => blah,blah2
`Column Objects =>192.168.0.1...,192.168.1.1...
`Column Objects =>192.168.0.1...,192.168.1.1...
```

So far I have been able to open the file read it and do a split but its not scalable at all. What I would ideally like to do is to have anything between object-group and the next object-group put into an array with the various values of that object-group as part of the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use below data structure. It's  well formed and easy to access.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $filename = 'file.txt';
open (my $fh, "<", $filename) or die $!;

my %data_for_object;
my $key;

while(<$fh>){
    chomp;
    if ($_ =~ /object-group network (.*)/){
        $key = $1;
    }
    else{
        if ($_ =~ /description (.*)/){
            $data_for_object{$key}{description} = $1;
        }
        if ($_ =~ /network-object host (.*)/){
            if (exists $data_for_object{$key}{host}){
                push @{$data_for_object{$key}{host}}, $1;
            }
            else{
                $data_for_object{$key}{host} = [$1];
            }
        }
    }
}

print Dumper \%data_for_object;
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'og-net-network-hostname-blah ' => {
                                               'host' => [
                                                           '192.168.0.1',
                                                           '192.168.0.2',
                                                           '192.168.0.3',
                                                           '192.168.0.4',
                                                           '192.168.0.5',
                                                           '192.168.0.6'
                                                         ],
                                               'description' => 'blah'
                                             },
          'og-net-network-hostname-anotherblah ' => {
                                                      'host' => [
                                                                  '192.168.1.1',
                                                                  '192.168.1.2',
                                                                  '192.168.1.3',
                                                                  '192.168.1.4',
                                                                  '192.168.1.5',
                                                                  '192.168.1.6'
                                                                ],
                                                      'description' => 'blah2'
                                                    }
        };
```

Also see:

- [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)
- [DBI](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI)

Comment: Just as a extra question, how would I then add all the hosts to a database, I have the DB connection working and its inputting all the other stuff correctly but not all the hosts. Seems to only add one host of the hosts section. Seems to be adding the first host to one array and then all the other hosts to another array, It prints out fine using Data::Dumper but not working to insert into databases?